# How to disable CTRL acting on touchpad's momentum in Cinnamon?

Tags: x11, xfce, cinnamon, touchpad

My touchpad has momentum enabled (or inertia, I do not know what the correct term is) - that is, even after my fingers leave the touchpad, it continues scrolling and gradually slows down (I believe it is a feature of every touchpad). However, in my Linux Mint Cinnamon, even in the momentum of the touchpad, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  works, and often, when I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  right after scrolling, it suddenly zooms in or out, as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + scrolling changes zoom. How can I fix this such that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  will not act upon the touchpad's momentum?

Comment: Aha! I have this exact same problem as well.

Comment: This is due to the driver architecture and as far as I know [it won't be fixed.](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=76094)

Comment: @don_crissti Yes, apparently it's not X's fault. FWIW I filed a [bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-28800) with Qt a couple of years about this (for KDE).

Comment: @don_crissti you can not even add a comment to the report anymore. See my answer.

Comment: Can yo edit the question to be more general, as there seems not to be Cinnamon specific answer?

Comment: @Sparhawk The problem can be solved X. See my answer.

Comment: @cat does my answer work for you?

Comment: Thanks @jarno. I no longer have a touchpad/laptop.

Answer (score 6):

This is since coasting has been implemented in the libinput drivers, ostensibly to improve usability, but with side effects (originating in the translation to X11 events) that you are experiencing.

Increasing the coasting friction can help with the issue. This works by killing the scrolling much faster after your fingers leave the touchpad, causing the libinput X11 driver to generate fewer scroll events and making an event-key clash much less likely. If you want to keep some level of coasting, then you may need to play around with the second number after "Synaptics Coasting Speed" below to find one that works for you - higher values stop the coasting more quickly, lower values let it slide for longer.

From the guidance [here (and other comments below)](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=38909#c5) I find this fixes the issue for me:

```
xinput set-prop "16" "Synaptics Coasting Speed" 20.0 50000.0
```

You will probably need to change the 16 to the ID of your touchpad device, which can be identified by using

```
xinput list
```

And to make the changes persist between sessions, create a file `.config/autostart/fix-scrolling.desktop` with the contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Fix Scrolling
Exec=xinput set-prop "16" "Synaptics Coasting Speed" 20.0 50000.0
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=false
```

In the long term, the X11 method of representing scroll events as discrete key presses should become less of an issue as more distributions shift to supporting Wayland or other modern "seat" architecture.

Comment: What exactly does your provided command solution do?

Comment: I've added an explanation of what the added command property setting does to the answer, let me know if anything else would be better with more clarification.

Comment: This is a great solution, but not exactly the solution I was looking for. I'm adding to my answer what I am looking for. I am hoping to find a way that doesn't stop coasting at all, but just disables the Control modifier acting on it.

Comment: Unfortunately, as the comments to your question indicate, this is unlikely to be solved by the upstream developers.One possible option may be to develop a small utility to intercept scroll events by using something like https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/XEvIE/ . Another is probably to change the keybinding of the scroll in/out within the affected utilities to be something other than CTRL+Mousewheel, maybe to SUPER?

Comment: Sadly, my pointer device (Logitech K400) does not have property  "Synaptics Coasting Speed".

Comment: I use Xinput extension in my answer.

Comment: One issue with this is that the device id seems to change at different times. Not entirely sure why, but previously my Synaptics device id was 13, but it is 15 now. It might make sense to point the autostart at a script that determines the device id at boot time.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is not limited to *Cinnamon DE*. For example *Xfce4* has <kbd>Alt</kbd> key bound to desktop zooming by default, if compositor is enabled. There in *Window Manager Tweaks* dialog you can modify "Key used to grab and move windows" setting in Accessibility tab to change or disable the modifier key for the actions, but those actions are useful, so I do not want to disable them. (Despite the name it affects to desktop zooming, too, see this [bug report](https://gitlab.xfce.org/xfce/xfwm4/-/issues/276).)

I solved this problem by creating software that disables given pointer device during scrolling, if a modifier key is pressed after scrolling has started, and re-enabling it when all modifier keys are released.

My solution is available in [this](https://github.com/jarnos/block-scroll-mod-x11) GitHub repository. At the time of writing this there is only a solution in the *gawk* branch that uses `gawk` and `xinput` so you should have those packages installed. Just download the shell script found in there and make it executable by `chmod +x` and run it. It will give more instructions in terminal, if you run it without arguments.

This solution is supposed to work, if your desktop environment uses *X Window System (X11)* and it works for all applications there including e.g. *Google Chrome* (that has bound <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> with scroll for zooming). It seems there is no equivalent solution for *Wayland* if keyboard and touchpad are in a same device, see [here](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libinput/libinput/-/issues/411#note_577697).

Comment: Interesting, thanks.

Comment: @e2-e4 does it work for you?

Comment: Good script. The only issue I have is that the scrolling stops only after the modifier has been pressed, which for me means at least one scroll event is still sent - instead of the fonts becoming tiny/huge, they become one step smaller/larger - which is an improvement, but not a complete solution.

Comment: @TeresaeJunior thanks for feedback. To avoid the race condition one needs a method to block mouse events on demand before X or other windowing system gets them.

Answer (score 0):

What works for me is:

```
synclient CoastingFriction=1000
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't persist after a reboot, so you'll need to run it on startup. I added it as a custom command in "Startup Applications" and now I don't have any more accidental zooming when switching browser tabs!