# Google Chrome accidental zoom

Tags: ubuntu, chrome

I have noticed that sometimes my Chrome under Ubuntu increases zoom level. Usually, it happens when I am doing something on the keyboard so perhaps it is some touchpad or keys combinations which I am accidentally touching. I know for sure that this is not standard Ctrl+ but could not figure out what it is in order to disable it. Are there any other ZOOM keyboard shortcuts on Chrome/Linux? My current Chrome version is 54.0.2840.100.

Comment: for gnome: https://wiki.gnome.org/Design/OS/KeyboardShortcuts, but you're probably using unity, google "unity accessibility shortcuts", zoom is an accessibility feature

Comment: ctrl+0 resets zoom to default

Comment: I think I have the same problem and I know when it happens, but don't know the solution. I hope it helps. This is the steps when it happen:

Comment: I think I have the same problem, but don't know the solution. 
I hope it helps.

This is the steps when it happens:
- I'm scrolling over some web page
- Press ctrl key to do ctrl+w shortcut to close the tab before the scroll ends
- The tab closes, but Chrome has zoomed out because the ctrl+scroll shortcut

When I come back to the site site chrome apply the zoom and I have to reset it with ctrl+0.

I suppose the prolem is not chrome but linux. Limiting the scrolling shortcuts to those that have the main key (ctrl) pressed before the scroll starts and ignore the rest may solve this.

Comment: It might be Unity related. I switched to i3 window manager and have not had this problem since.

Comment: I tried i3 and it happens even there.

Comment: My [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1521647/490855) to a related question prevents those accidental zooms, but it may prevent too much currently.

Comment: If you use X, [this](https://github.com/jarnos/block-scroll-mod-x11) repository may help you in avoiding accidental zooming without totally disabling mousewheel/touchpad scrolling. In Xfce4 I have e.g. alt-scroll binding for desktop zooming by default when using the compsitor, so Chrome is not the only one.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Scroll changes the zoom level in Chrome. You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> to reset it to the default zoom level. You can also zoom out with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>- (Minus)</kbd> and zoom in with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>= (Equals)</kbd>.

Now, even knowing this, I still have this happen often. It sort of seems like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is sticky in Ubuntu (or maybe I just hold it down longer than I realize :-P ).

Comment: Note also that Chrome will store the zoom level per site, so on next visit you will have the same (possibly wrong) zoom.

Comment: I guess the logical question from here is: how to disable that "feature" in Chrome? On a laptop this unwanted zoom happens too often (press Ctrl, and barely brush the touchpad and voilà... Not sure it's an Unix thing, though)

Comment: The Ctrl is not sticky and you do not hold it too long, but with some pointer hardware and driver scrolling events may appear also sometime after you have stopped scrolling. That is called inertial scrolling.

Comment: @jarno I mean the other way around, like I let go of Ctrl then scroll, and the page zooms.

Comment: One thing is that the zooming operation is slow and thus the event buffer is consumed some time still after you release Ctrl. But do you mean that when there is no scrolling you press and release Ctrl and thereafter scroll, you get zoom?

Comment: @e2-e4 I think my [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1521647/490855) to a related question will help you.

Comment: @jamo nice work!

Comment: @e2-e4 I made another solution that is less restrictive. See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/612499/111181).

Answer (score 0):

This is likely caused by [Chromium bug 253697](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=253697).

To fix this, disable inertial scrolling by running the following command in a terminal window:

```
 synclient CoastingSpeed=0
```

Comment: It exits with error: "Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?"

Comment: But it might work for some who have different pointer device hardware.