# Can I globally disable kinetic scrolling on touchpad?

Tags: touchpad, scrolling, gtk3

I want to scroll exactly the distance I scroll, not twice as far. I'm sure kinetic scrolling is amazing for touch devices, but touchpads are no more touch devices than keyboards, where you touch the keys.

Comment: List properties of your touchpad with `xinput`, see if you can disable it. To make that permanent, one option is to create your own `xorg.conf`. Careful, the property names will be different, see manpage of the touchpad driver.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not in the touchpad driver, since GTK3 is the only toolkit that does it. There's nothing that seems particularly relevant in `xinput list-props 12` (my touchpad), either.

Comment: Some touchpad driver has [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/270408/111181) option.

Comment: See [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/1049965/21005) question about how to find the driver. I seem to have libinput driver used for my Logitech K400, but I can not find a relevant property.

Comment: I filed a [bug report](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libinput/libinput/issues/411) against libinput.